# Mapping unmanaged data to a managed structure in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, unmanaged

I have spent many hours working with unmanaged code, and platform invoke in .NET. The code below illustrates something that is puzzling me regarding how unmanaged data is mapped to a managed object in .NET.

For this example I am going to use the [RECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd162897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure:

**C++ RECT implementation (unmanaged Win32 API)**

```
typedef struct _RECT {
  LONG left;
  LONG top;
  LONG right;
  LONG bottom;
} RECT, *PRECT;
```

**C# RECT implementation (managed .NET/C#)**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int left, top, right, bottom;
}
```

Okay, so my C# equivalent should work, right? I mean, all of the variables are in the same order as the C++ struct, and it's using the same variable names.

My assumption of `LayoutKind.Sequential` means that the unmanaged data is mapped to the managed object in the same sequence it appears in the C++ structure. i.e. the data will be mapped, starting with left, then top, then right, then bottom.

On this basis I should be able to modify my C# structure...

**C# RECT implementation (a bit cleaner)**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Rect //I've started by giving it a .NET compliant name
{
    private int _left, _top, _right, _bottom; // variables are no longer directly accessible.

    /* I can now access the coordinates via properties */
    public Int32 Left
    {
        get { return _left; }
        set { this._left = value; }
    }

    public Int32 Top
    {
        get { return _top; }
        set { this._top = value; }
    }

    public Int32 Right
    {
        get { return _right; }
        set { this._right = value; }
    }

    public Int32 Bottom
    {
        get { return _bottom; }
        set { this._bottom = value; }
    }
}
```

So what happens if the variables are declared in the wrong order? Presumably this screws up the coordinates because they will no longer be mapped to the correct thing?

```
public struct RECT
{
    public int top, right, bottom, left;
}
```

At a guess, this would map like so:

> top = left
>
> right = top
>
> bottom = right
>
> left = bottom

So my question is simply, Am I correct in my assumption that, I can modify the managed structure in terms of the access specifier of each variable, and even the variable name, but I cannot alter the order of the variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to change the order of your member variables, you can do it by using the [`FieldOffsetAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute.aspx). Just makes it a little bit less readable.

You'll also need to set your [`StructLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) to [`LayoutKind.Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx) to indicate you are setting the offsets yourself.

Example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct RECT
{
    [FieldOffset(4)]  public int top;
    [FieldOffset(8)]  public int right;
    [FieldOffset(12)] public int bottom;
    [FieldOffset(0)]  public int left;
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Concise and easy to understand. +1

Comment: You really really really do not want to do this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems that your thinking is OK. `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)` is the default value applied to C# `struct` so you don't even need to do this. But if you would like to have different order of fields you can do this by using `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicite)` and then apply `FieldOffset` attribute to each field - this is much better approach since you make explicite what is implicite and no longer are you depending on something that can easly be changed like field definition order.

Take a look at MSDN sample: [`StructLayoutAttribute Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) and it should be clearer. Also - create sample application in C++ and C# and play with it to get a hang of it - it will benefit you greatly.

Answer (score 1):

The default mapping of a `struct` in C# is `LayoutKind.Sequential`. This prevents the compiler from optimizing memory by rearranging the variables and assure correct mapping.

You may however tell the compiler a different order of the variables by using `LayoutKind.Explicit`, and `FieldOffsetAttribute`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Rect
{
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public int right;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public int top;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int left;

    [FieldOffset(12)]
    public int bottom;
}
```

The value of the `FieldOffsetAttribute` indicates the byte position in the struct of the start of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I correct in my assumption that, I can modify the managed structure in terms of the access specifier of each variable, and even the variable name, but I cannot alter the order of the variables?

Yes, that is correct. Neither the access specifier, nor the variable name has any impact on the way the struct is laid out.